# Json object working in return but not outside return in render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am receiving a very unusual error with my Object. I am trying to get the value of the key `name` from an object which looks like this

```
{id: 3,

image_url: "anticon anticon-gift",

is_deleted: false,

name: "Inform Partners",

org_id: null",}
```

The thing is I have an object coming from a state in a variable let us say `this.state.description_data` it looks like this

[image: this.state.description_data]

As you can see I am getting a `category_id` in it. I want to match that `category_id` from another state object which is

[image: this.state.category_data]

Now, I want to match the category_id iIgot from description_data with the id in category_data and get the value of `name` from it and show it in the render. I get the value but after a few refreshing or by going out of the page and coming back in it shows me error as follows

[image: error]

I have tried this code to get the value

```
var defaultCategoryId= this.state.description_data.map(c=>{
            return c.category_id
        });
        console.log("description_data")
        console.log(this.state.description_data)
        console.log(defaultCategoryId[0])
        console.log(this.state.category_data)

        let catId= defaultCategoryId[0] -1;
        let defaultCategoryValue = this.state.category_data[catId];

        // let catValue=defaultCategoryValue.map(c=>{
        //     return c.name
        // });
        console.log(defaultCategoryValue);
```

The object i mentioned above is being generated in the variable `let defaultCategoryValue`

I am using the `defaultCategoryValue.name` in render method which looks like this:

return (

```
    <Spin spinning={this.state.loading} tip="Loading..." indicator={antIcon} delay={500} size="large">
           
       {this.state.cover_show===false?<div>
            {this.state.description_data.map(d=>
            <div key={d.id}>
             <Row key={d.id} style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start" style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>
                                <Col md={16} sm={12} xs={24} >
                                    <div className="form-element">
                                        <label className="label-class" title="">Production Name <Tooltip title="This is a name used that you can use to uniquely identify your production, making it easier for you and your contributors to find it. We recommend the name be a few words that describe the nature of the project."><Icon className="tooltip-icon" type="question-circle-o" /></Tooltip> </label>
                                        <Input className="txt-font"  name="display_app_name" id={"display_app_name-" + d.id} maxLength={70}  defaultValue={d.display_app_name} onChange={this.ontxtChange} />
                                        <span className="error-text">{this.validator.message('display_app_name', d.display_app_name, 'required|max:70', false, { default: 'This field is required.',max:'You have exceeded the maximum character limit.' })}</span>
                                        <p style={{float:"right"}}>{d.display_app_name.length}/70</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-element">
                                        <label className="label-class" title="">Category <Tooltip title="This is where you can specify which of the options most closely aligns with the purpose of the video. If you are using a pre-built storyboard, this will have already been selected for you."><Icon className="tooltip-icon" type="question-circle-o" /></Tooltip> </label>
                                        <Select defaultValue={defaultCategoryValue.name} onChange={this.onCategoryChange} id={"category_id-" + d.id}>
                                            {categoryOptions}
                                        </Select>
                                        <span className="error-text">{this.validator.message('category_id', d.category_id, 'required', false, { default: 'This field is required.'})}</span>
                                    </div>
```

Probably the way i am getting the value is wrong. I am assuming this because if i dont type `defaultCategoryValue.name` and write `d.category_id` i dont get any error. The defaultCategoryValue always revieves the data no matter how many times i refresh. But it shows error sometimes if you use it in `<Select defaultValue={defaultCategoryValue.name>` as you can see above in the code.

Please help me with this guys. Thank you.

Comment: you are not setting the state object

Comment: Its set above in the code in a function. As you can see I am retrieving data in console.log()

Answer (score 0):

Given the shape for `this.state.description_data` to be

```
[
   {
    //...
    category_id
    //...
   }
]
```

and `this.state.category_data` to be

```
[
   {
    //...
    id
    //...
   }
]
```

It seems about right to convert `this.state.category_data` from an array to an object having its keys to be the `category_id`. This will make it easier to lookup the category data for a `category_id` when mapping `this.state.description_data`

```
const CATEGORY_DATA = this.state.category_data.reduce(
                        (categories, category) => (
                          {...categories, [category.id]: category}
                        ), 
                        {}
                      )
```

Now, `this.state.description_data` can be mapped to its category data in the following way.

```
this.state.description_data.map(
  (description) => (
    <div key={description.id}>
      //...
      <Select 
        defaultValue={CATEGORY_DATA[description.category_id]}
        id={"category_id-" + description.id}
        onChange={this.onCategoryChange}
      >
        {categoryOptions}
      </Select>
      //...
    </div> 
  )
)
```